# MirroredStrategy: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tensorflow 2.0 to train a model, my data pipeline and model train fine with `tf.keras.Model.fit()` on a single gpu, but when I try running it on multi gpu with `MirroredStrategy`.

My dataset is obtained with something like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(records)
dataset.map(parse_and_decode)
map_augmentation = lambda *args: tf.py_function(
    augmentation,
    [*args],
    4*[tf.float32]
)
dataset.map(map_augmentation)

def map_ground_truth(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    ret_values = tf.py_function(
        get_ground_truth,
        [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4],
        [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32
    )
    # set_shape based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24520
    for ret_val in ret_values:
        ret_val.set_shape([None for _ in range(3)])
    return *ret_values

dataset.map(map_ground_truth)

model.fit(dataset)
```

This works ok without using `MirroredStrategy` but when I introduce it I get this error:

```
_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'crowd_mask:0' shape=(1, 401, 401, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'unannotated_mask:0' shape=(1, 401, 401, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'kp_maps_true:0' shape=(1, 401, 401, 17) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'mid_offsets/Identity:0' shape=(1, 13, 13, 64) dtype=float32>]
```

(in the `strategy.scope()` are the model and losses creations, the model `compile` and the `fit`. No manual call to `strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset` is done on the dataset as this is aparently handled by the `fit` function).

Comment: same here. Without strategy, fitting model works well but it raises the same error with strategy.

Comment: Can you check this thread - https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/519